# Facebook Activity Privacy

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, privacy

I am using the FB Javascript SDK to create an activity, the activity is posting fine but the documentation for how to set the privacy of an activity doesn't really give me anything. I have followed the documentation on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/

I get an error when using the following code:

```
var fb_privacy = '{"value":"PRIVATE"}';
fb_privacy = encodeURIComponent(fb_privacy);

Error: (#100) privacy must contains a valid privacy 'value'
```

I have also tried the value "SELF" which yielded the same error. It says privacy is suppose to be a JSON encoded string but I can't seem to get anything to work currently.

Comment: why are you encoding the json string, have you tried without?

%7B%22value%22%3A%22PRIVATE%22%7D

Comment: i'm fairly certain it didn't work, but I'll give it a try again just to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

try this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/ with only this text {'value':'EVERYONE'} i have tested 5 minutes ago =)

use ' not "